# How to find the value $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n-1}$ converges to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

We have been finding the value of sums related to the Harmonic series by using that

$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}= ln(N)+\gamma + \varepsilon_N$.

When I try to calculate  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n-1}$ using that method there is a point where I don´t know how to continue.

I have read that its value is $\frac{\pi}{4}$ but I don´t understand how is that obtained and I would like to know if it´s possible to solve it using the method I know.

This is what I did:

$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}$

$S_{2N}=\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n-1}=-1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}+...-\frac{1}{4N-3}+\frac{1}{4N-1}=$

$=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+...+\frac{1}{4N-1}-2(1+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{9}+...+\frac{1}{4N-3})=\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{1}{2n-1}-2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{4n-3}$

.

$\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{1}{2n-1}=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+...+\frac{1}{4N-3}+\frac{1}{4N-1}=$

$=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{4N-1}+\frac{1}{4N}-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{4N})=\sum_{n=1}^{4N}\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{1}{n}$

.

But I don´t know what to do with the second one. I tried to write it like this:

$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{4n-3}=1+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{9}+...+\frac{1}{4N-3}=$

$=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+...+\frac{1}{4N-3}+\frac{1}{4N-1}-(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+...\frac{1}{4N-1})=\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{1}{2n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{4n-1}$

Wich didn´t help because I find $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{4n-1}$ as difficult to solve as $\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{4n-3}$ and I have no idea of what else to do.

Comment: Hint: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$$ where $(a_n)$ has period $4$ hence $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^4\alpha_ki^{kn}$$ since $i$ is a principal fourth root of $1$, for some given $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)$ independent of $n$. Now, it happens that $\alpha_4=0$. And remains to compute $$u(i^k)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{i^{kn}}n$$ for $k=1$, $k=2$ and $k=3$. Can you do that? At the end, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n-1}=\alpha_1u(i)+\alpha_2u(-1)+\alpha_3u(-i)$$

Comment: We are still doing only real analysis, so sadly I can´t use that

Comment: The list of tools you **cannot** use grows longer any minute, it seems (see your comment to the answer below for another example). Say, what are the tools you **can** use?

Comment: Silence... Probably not either the identity $$\pi\cot(\pi z)=\frac1z+2z\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{z^2-n^2}$$ at $z=\frac14$...

Comment: No, not either. As I said below, right now can´t use almost anything other than the method we have been taught to use for this series and I wanted to know if that was enogh

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, this sum requires more than playing with the asymptotic development of the harmonic series.

I suggest that you consider “instead” $$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}}=\int_0^1{\sum_{k=0}^n{(-x^2)^n}\,dx},$$ and then prove that $$\left|S_n-\int_0^1{\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx}\right| \leq n^{-1}.$$

Comment: Problem is, we haven´t learned integration yet

Comment: Is this homework? What are the mathematical tools you can/may/know how to use?

Comment: Well, its not homework, just something I found while I was practising similar series. My professor looked at it briefly and said we could probably solve it, but we have started with series recently and thats pretty much the only way I know to do this type. I wanted to know if I was missing something that allowed me to do it like that.

Comment: Ok. But I do not know of any way to involve $\pi$ in a calculation that uses neither integrals nor a bit of complex analysis. Besides, if your partial sum could be expressed with harmonic sums, you would get a relation between $\gamma$ and $\pi$ (The rest of the expansion has rational coefficients), and I am quite sure we do not really know one.